# How can express a foreign key like constraint in SQL Server using a trigger (or otherwise)?

Tags: sql-server

Column fk_id in table A references records in table B having a primary key of pk_id. The rule is fk_id in B must reference a valid value of pk_id in A or else it must be -1. I'd much rather have fk_id in B be nullable and enforce the rule as a foreign key constraint but I can't change this design. If I understand correctly the way to enforce this rule is with a trigger on updates and insertions. What is the best way to write a trigger like this, or if there is a better way to enforce it, how can it be done?

Comment: Why not create a row in your parent table with an ID of -1 and then set the key back to check? If you have a foreign key that allows values that aren't in the parent table (even if it's only 1 specific value), then the key is untrusted, and thus (almost) useless.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Yes, this can be done with a trigger. No - the best way is with a proper foreign key relationship (requiring a change in design, as you know). And btw - you will need to write triggers for both tables. Give it a try and then ask specific coding questions when needed.